# How do I find out how my git repository is configured?

Tags: git

I have a running git folder where I can push my commits to the remote repository, but I didn't configure it myself.

How can I find out how it is configured? Where does it push to, wiht which username and method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into .git/config for example.

For listing your remote repositories

```
git remote -v
```

or simple have a look into

```
git remote --help
```

to see all info available:

```
git config -l
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git config -l
```

*and 30 characters for post the anser*